# use enviroment variables instead of "Path Variables" in paths in intellijidea

Tags: intellij-idea

I am already aware of Path Variable but is there's a way to use environment variables in paths instead of path variables in intellijidea, I have tried using the syntax ${VAR} but it doesn't work, and tried also the Path variable syntax $VAR$ but it works with Path Variables only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Peter Gromov answer, I have decided to create a simple plugin for this.

"Environment Variables in Path Variables" plugin:

github repo: https://github.com/mohamedkomalo/env-vars-in-path-vars

on jetbrains: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8063

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no such possibility in IntelliJ IDEA.